# WSL2 suddenly writing to system32 instead of network share

Tags: backup, network-shares, scheduled-tasks, wsl2

I am running wsl2 on `Windows10 1909`. I need to backup some data from a wsl2 folder to a network share. Therefore, I wrote a backup script which seems to be working fine when running manually. The network share is mounted under WSL and accessible, when the script starts, backup folders are created on it and the script starts copying the files.

However, when I scheduled the script via windows' task scheduler to run in the night, I discovered in the morning, that no files nor a folder was created on the networkshare, but - however - the whole backup folder was created in windows' `system32` folder.
I checked whether the network share was still mounted, and everything looks fine, I can access it in wsl2 without a problem.
This now happened two times in a row for me.

Does anyone know why WSL suddenly breaks and writes those files to `system32`?
Does this indicate that the connection to the network share got lost during the process (but why are there no files at all? At least some should have worked then). Or could this be related to the task scheduler, that - although I scheduled my own account to execute the task - it lacks some permissions?

The script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
timestamp=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
path=/mnt/x/backup
maxBackups=4

if [[ $(id -u) > 0 ]]; then
    echo "Please run the script as root."
    exit 1
fi

echo "Timestamp is $timestamp"
echo "Backup path is $path"
cd ${path}
directoryCount=$(find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l)
echo "Found $directoryCount backups in this folder. MaxBackups is set to $maxBackups"
if [[ $directoryCount -ge $maxBackups ]];then
    # Old backups are deleted here [...]
else
    echo "No need to delete backups."
fi
echo "Creating directories..."
mkdir ${timestamp}
cd ${timestamp}
mkdir databases
mkdir data
cd databases
echo "Dumping databases..."
# Databases are being dumped
echo "Databases written to backup folder."
cd ..
echo "Copying files, this will take a while!"
cp -R /opt/data data/
echo "Files copied."
```

**EDIT:**

I was able to track down the problem. Apparently, the task is executed with admin privileges, which causes wsl to not have the network share mounted. `/etc/fstab` still has the correct entry, but calling `sudo mount -a` yields errors:

```
<3>init: (1139) ERROR: UtilCreateProcessAndWait:489: /bin/mount failed with status 0x2000                               
<3>init: (1139) ERROR: MountPlan9:478: mount cache=mmap,rw,trans=fd,rfdno=3,wfdno=3,msize=65536,aname=drvfs;path=X:;symlinkroot=/mnt/ failed 2
```

This results in the script not being able to execute `cd`.
However, I don't quite understand why 1) the task is executed with elevated privileges and not with user privileges as requested, and 2) this causes wsl to lack the mount of the network share.
Any ideas to fix this?

Comment: Which account does the scheduled task use for execution of the job? Mounted network are user and AFAIK session dependent, therefore you may need to add code for mounting the network share before performing the backup.

Comment: How does your script work? If you're using `cd` or `pushd`, do you check for failure?

Comment: Including your script might help - evidently it starts in `system32` and is unable to change folders.

Comment: I assigned the same user in the task scheduler as the one I use for running the script manually. I don't check for errors on cd, but I'll implement more error checking and logging in it

Comment: Change the working directory before copying files, the scheduled task may be running with admin priv.

Comment: To add to these other fine suggestions.  When running things as admin/root, windows defaults to system32 as it's startup directory.  You can verify this behavior by running a batch file as admin and echoing what %CD% is.  This means that @Biswapriyo, user1686, and harrymc are saying are all on the money.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! I was able to track down the error a bit further and edited my post

Comment: Does anyone know why the script seems to be executed with different permissions, although I selected the same user in the task scheduler?